# How to always change the position of EVERY element in a list in python when shuffling

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, shuffle

I want the position of all elements in a list to change when i shuffle it. No element should remain at the same position or index.

I tried using random.shuffle but it doesn't always change the position of all elements in a list because as you can see below after x is shuffled the element 2 remains at index 1.

```
    >>> import random
    >>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    >>> random.shuffle(x)
    >>> x
    [5, 2, 4, 3, 1]
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen in the event `0 <= len(x) <= 1`?